# How to log back in using SSH after logging out?

Tags: python, ssh, google-cloud-platform

I logged out of my jupyter notebook which I had set up on my google cloud using SSH. Now, it needs password to log me in again.
To log back in (and get a password), I use the following code in the SSH window:

```
jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --no-browser &
```

and I get this message:

```
I 18:06:11.509 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:06:11.509 NotebookApp] The port 8889 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:06:11.509 NotebookApp] The port 8890 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:06:11.510 NotebookApp] The port 8891 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:06:11.510 NotebookApp] The port 8892 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 18:06:14.111 NotebookApp] jupyter_tensorboard extension loaded.
[I 18:06:14.188 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jupyterlab
[I 18:06:14.189 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab
[I 18:06:14.269 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/m_saljooghian
[I 18:06:14.269 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 18:06:14.269 NotebookApp] http://(strongestf or 127.0.0.1):8827/?token=b996457bf3ce30f4da4d1f78f32e8592aa500bceef1b42e7
[I 18:06:14.269 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 18:06:14.273 NotebookApp] 

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/m_saljooghian/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-3875-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://(strongestf or 127.0.0.1):8827/?token=b996457bf3ce30f4da4d1f78f32e8592aa500bceef1b42e7
```

My initial port is 8888, but when I use the token for port 8888, it says "invalid credentials." when I try port 8827 (which is assigned by the SSH), the web page doesn't open. It says "This site can’t be reached."

I know my question is messy, but I did not know what else I should include. I appreciate your solutions or even suggestions to improve this question.

Comment: may i suggest that you first clean up all existing jupyter notebook processes by killing them? You have so many jupyter processes already bound to ports 8888, 8889, 8892 and so on.

you can use netstat -tulpn | grep 8888 to get the PID of the jupyter process running on 8888 port and then kill it.

Comment: Sure. How should I do that?

Comment: I have edited my comment with the steps

Comment: I used the command and received this message: ```(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8888            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1101/python3 ```

Comment: That is okay, we are not trying to kill processes not started by you. So yes 1101 is the PID of the jupyter process you started when you first ran the jupyter command. By Default jupyter binds itself to port 8888, if you start a second jupyter process without killing the existing one , then it will start looking for 8889 and so on. Please kill all jupyter processes you are not using. 

Now try again. It is possible that the Google Cloud admin has only opened port 8888 so you will be able to run jupyter only on that port. Maybe that is why you get connection errors on 8827 port

Comment: yes. In my firewall setting, I used port 8888. So I guess only port 8888 can be used. But Can you tell me what code (codes) I should use to kill all the existing processes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196424/discussion-between-pie-ton-and-thalish-sajeed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have opened only the port 8888 in your GCP network settings so you will get connection refused on any other port. Try to kill your existing jupyter processes and free up port 8888 and try again